# Java DrEdit won't run on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble getting DrEdit run on Google App Engine.
I get the error message:
500 Server Error

I have tried to follow the instructions on the following page:
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/java

However, when I get to the following instruction:

1. In the Eclipse Build Path editor for the project, add all of the JARs in the  and  directories to the project's build path.

I have a problem!

In Eclipse I am using appengine-java-sdk-1.7.3

DrEdit seems to have been created with appengine-java-sdk-1.6.3 when I try to add jars from the DrEdit repository I end up with a mixture of the two versions.

So I have added DrEdit in a different way.

Basically I added API's instead of jars from the Repository.

A more detailed explanation is as follows:

```
I created an Eclipse App Engine project
then copied the source files from com.google.drive.samples.dredit
to my own com.google.drive.samples.dredit
and I copied the source files from com.google.drive.samples.dredit.model
to my own com.google.drive.samples.dredit.model
```

I also copied the static directory file structure to my own war directory.

I also copied the repositories web.xml, appengine-web.xml, client_secrets.json and logging.properties

I also copied the templates directory with the index.jsp

Then I added the Drive API and Google OAuth2 API to get rid of the red crosses shown on the source files.

I also deleted the index.html

I put the correct details in the client_secrets.json file and put my app identity in the appengine-web.xml

The file structure looks like the following

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-3Lh3PoZeTec/UKzXDfCzTlI/AAAAAAAAC98/ELcsRmhiCg0/s789/DrEditFileStructure3.png

When I try to run on the Google App Engine I get the 500 Server Error.
In the log I get the following stack trace

Here is the stack trace

```
78.147.107.157 - - [22/Nov/2012:02:50:16 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11" "oauth2dredit.appspot.com" ms=2303 cpu_ms=1039 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c1af24ed12b197a737ba95b241e522f
W 2012-11-22 02:50:16.055
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1a02097{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~oauth2dredit/1.363349173399555415}
org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/AboutServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/FileServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/StartPageServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/UserServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:656)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/AboutServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b3e6d785ba51dcea(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/FileServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b3e6d785ba51dcea(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/StartPageServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b3e6d785ba51dcea(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
<continued in next message>
W 2012-11-22 02:50:16.055
<continued from previous message>
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/drive/samples/dredit/UserServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-b3e6d785ba51dcea(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
C 2012-11-22 02:50:16.060
Uncaught exception from servlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:228)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
I 2012-11-22 02:50:16.062
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you're building using Java 7, switch to 6. GAE only just added initial support for 7 in 1.7.3, but I've never seen it working yet.